How to fix image import
I am learning react. In the source code when i try to import the image the whole function is not rendered and opening the web page does not display anything, however when i comment the 2 lines for importing and placing the image in the header section all seems to work well. I get the desired output on the webpage. How could i fix my code and any advice.
index.js file
import logo from "../images/reactLogo.png" //comment this
function HeaderInfo(){
    return(
        <header className="header">
            <div className="logoContainer">
                <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="logo"/> //comment this
                <h3>ReactFacts</h3>
            </div>
            <h4>React Course-Project 1</h4>
        </header>
    )
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello React</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="./js/index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>

I checked the file location of my image and it is okay.

You can place your image in the public -> images directory and access the image using "/images/reactLogo.png" and not using "../images".
Tell me if it works or not.

Can you provide the current file structure - need more clarity on how your files are relatively placed in the project?
